# Angularjs enable and disable all textboxes when i empty one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, input, disabled-input

I am beginner in web development and I want to learn more about how I can do controls on my inputs and select.
I have one select and four input.

I want to disable all other input and the select if I select an option or I enter a text in my input

Sorry for my English, can you help me with the AngularJS part, it's important I want to do it with AngularJS.

When the other inputs of selects are disabled I need to display a message for explain why it's impossible to use other input or select

I don't know how I can do, but I think I need to use `ng-model` , `ng-disabled`, `ng-change`, maybe `ng-blur` and `ng-focus`

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Select1">Choix</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                <option>choix 1</option>
                <option>choix 2</option>
                <option>choix 3</option>
                <option>choix 4</option>
                <option>choix 5</option>
            </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Input1">Choix A</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input1" placeholder="Choix A">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Input2">Choix B</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input2" placeholder="Choix B">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Input3">Choix C</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input3" placeholder="Choix C">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Input4">Choix D</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input4" placeholder="Choix D">
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks for your future help .

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-model in selectedChoix to get the value of selected option and ng-disabled if there have no selectedChoix.

Choix
        
            choix 1
            choix 2
            choix 3
            choix 4
            choix 5

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Input1">Choix A</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input1" placeholder="Choix A" ng-disabled="!selectedChoix">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Input2">Choix B</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input2" placeholder="Choix B" ng-disabled="!selectedChoix">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Input3">Choix C</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input3" placeholder="Choix C" ng-disabled="!selectedChoix">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Choix D">Email address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input4" placeholder="Choix D" ng-disabled="!selectedChoix">
</div>
```

This will automatically disabled other input fields until select any option.When select a option then other input fields will enable to write.

you can write your message anywhere until select any option or can use tooltip.

Comment: Thanks Forid, i will try it :)